# how to pass a JavaScript var into a @... Razor statement?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have the folowing problem, I have a Javascript war and need to pass it into a RazorView statment like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var myID = ...
    @MyREazorCall(myID);
</script>
```

I get the message: `"myID" is not available in this context`

how to solve this?

Comment: because myID should be a razor variable not js variable

Comment: No way to get this working? the problem is, that the content from the myID is generated via JavaScript

Comment: Check smetad anarkist answer

Comment: What does "@MyREazorCall(myID);" return (assuming it would work)? A block of JavaScript? If so, can't you inject it using plain JS anyway?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the RazorView statement is executed on the server before the Javascript, you will probably have to alter your solution to allow the Javascript to run a ajax request and then your View/Controller will have to respond to that ajax request and then you handle the response in the Javascript.